# Zend2 list all methods of a given class

Tags: php

It must be a Zend way to get list of all methods of a class. Maybe somebody knows it? ReflectionClass doesn't work for me. This...

```
$f = new ReflectionClass('Admin\Controller\AclResourcesController');
```

gives me an error...

> Fatal error: Class 'Admin\Controller\ReflectionClass' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're inside a namespace, you need to make explicit references to global classes:

```
$f = new \ReflectionClass(...);
```

Or:

```
use ReflectionClass;

$f = new ReflectionClass(...);
```

Comment: Note that this is nothing really Zend-related, but rather a simple PHP namespace issue.